# Best practice to combine different Javascript SDKs callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jsapi

I've came across this situation a few times before and always found a tricky way to make it work but I'd like to know if there's a best practice for that:
Sometimes you have to use several JavaScript SDKs on a page example: Google jsapi and jQuery.

Google calls this function when the SDK is ready to be used:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(MyFunction);
```

jQuery does everything in this callback:

```
document.ready();
```

What if I want to manipulate the dom using jQuery AFTER Google's callback.
What's the best way to tell the browser: "Wait for jQuery AND Google to be ready and do the stuff..."
Is it best to have the jQuery callback nested inside Google callback? Or the other way round? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways, one of which is to use a global variable;

```
var googleLoaded = false;

google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
   googleLoaded = true;
   mainCallback();
});

document.ready(mainCallback);

function mainCallback(){ 
  if(googleLoaded){
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

As a general solution, you can do as given below

```
var jsLibsToLoad = 5;

jsLib1.onLoad(mainCallback);
jsLib2.onLoad(mainCallback);
jsLib3.onLoad(mainCallback);
jsLib4.onLoad(mainCallback);
jsLib5.onLoad(mainCallback);

function mainCallback(){ 
  if(!(--jsLibsToLoad)){
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use some AMD tool like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader, and it is really good with dependancy management. In your particular case (using of some traditional/legacy "browser globals" scripts) you should additionally use [Shim Config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

At the start using AMD is a little bit tricky, but it gave a great benefits when you get used to it. It will improve the speed and quality of your code.